# customizing the timer frequency in objectlistview events

Tags: c#, objectlistview

Is there any way to customize the timer frequency for **objectlistview** events?

To be more specific, I have a `_FormatCell` event for my **objectlistview**. It has some overheads on CPU utilization. I would be OK if the event would be called each 4 seconds. But right now it seems like it is called each less than 500 milliseconds. So is there any property / work around / hack to adjust the timer frequency for **objectlistview** events?

So far I have tried using `Thread.Sleep(4000);` in the event block but it caused a deadlock in my application.

Comment: `FormatCell` is called when you Refresh, Sort, Update, Change etc. items. It is not called periodically. Using `Thread.Sleep()` is probably blocking you application because the event is marshaled to the GUI thread. You should check when and how often you manipulate / refresh data. Why is it an issue that `FormatCell` is called "often"? As a side note, you can temporarily prevent all `FormatCell` calls by setting `objectListView1.UseCellFormatEvents = true`.

Comment: Thanks Rev. I already disabled format cell events and reduced the overhead to its third of it. I update the list object every four seconds but format cell seems more frequent than this.